# Cannot get attributes, period, in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm simply trying to select the ID of these particular "sides". I've done it a million times but jQuery just simply doesn't want to cooperate with me.

```
$( 'input[name="fd-border"]' ).change(function() {
    var border = [];
    var sides  = $( 'input[name="fd-border"]' );
    var length = sides.length;
    if ( length == 0 ) {
        border = [ 'top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right' ];
    } else {
        for ( i = 0; i < length; ++i ) {
            border.push( sides[i].val() );
        }
    }
```

The above query returns the following array:

```
[
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"fd-border-top" name=​"fd-border" value=​"top" class=​"ui-helper-hidden-accessible">​, 
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"fd-border-bottom" name=​"fd-border" value=​"bottom" class=​"ui-helper-hidden-accessible">​, 
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"fd-border-left" name=​"fd-border" value=​"left" class=​"ui-helper-hidden-accessible">​, 
<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"fd-border-right" name=​"fd-border" value=​"right" class=​"ui-helper-hidden-accessible">​
]
```

I just keep getting `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'sides[i].val()')`. It doesn't matter if I want to use `.val()`, or `.attr( 'id' )`, or any attribute for that matter. I get the same error, and it's only happening here. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
border.push( $(sides[i]).val() );
```

because `sides[i]` gives a dom reference which does not have methods like `.val()` or `.attr()`, you need to get the corresponding jQuery object by wrapping it using `$(sides[i])`

Instead of the `for` loop I may use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
border = sides.map(function(idx, el){
    return $(el).val()
})
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick and helpful response.